# Ads no longer work

Tags: bug, status-completed

Where the ads should be, I see a white box:

[image]

It doesn't matter which browser I use. There's no active ad blocker.

Clicking it takes me to a 404 page.  One possible link:

- https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/ct/1917

Is this broken for everyone?  Is it an SE bug?  It's been like this at least since yesterday.

Comment: Same for me (Windows 10, Chrome, Edge, and Internet Explorer).

Comment: Using Safari on OS X 10.10.2. The ads look OK.

Comment: For Chrome on mac os 10.10.5, they're blank.

Comment: Seems to be working now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fix has rolled out for these ads.  It might take up to 1 hour for cache to expire.  Sorry for the delay.